# On a calm day, what determines the active runway?

Tags: runways, wind

When the winds are "calm" or variable, and as such there is no wind direction on which to base the decision on what the active runway should be, how is that determination made?

Comment: Good question. I always imagined it was geography (which runway lines up best for incoming and outgoing flights, surrounding terrain, and possibly shortest distance to terminal), but I never actually knew.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Almost every airport that handles frequent traffic will have a **Preferential Runway Use Policy.** That policy will cover things such as which runways to use for departures and arrivals when **parallel runways** exist, and the preferred *direction* even in calm winds.

It's based on the best noise abatement routes/gradients, taxi distances, terrain, etc.

So much so the preferred direction can be used in **tail-wind** up to a limit (8 knots *component* in certain places for example). Basically it's the usage that was envisioned when the airport was designed (which [does take into account](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/29144/14897) the historic wind data).

[image]

> Westerly Operations is the **normal traffic pattern** used at LAX during the daytime (6:30 am to
>   midnight) throughout the year. Aircraft approach the airport from the east and depart the Airport
>   to the west due to the prevailing westerly wind. This procedure routes louder departing aircraft
>   to the west over the ocean, while arriving aircraft fly from the east to the west over the
>   communities on the eastside of LAX, including the Cities of Los Angeles, and Inglewood, and
>   the communities of Athens and Lennox.

Above ([source](https://www.lawa.org/uploadedFiles/LAX/noise/PDF/Final%20LAX%20Preferential%20Runway%20Use%20Policy%20Report%20041114_Web.pdf)) being the normal traffic pattern, it will remain so during calm winds.

---

Related:

- [In calm winds, which runway should I select at an untowered airport?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12550/14897)
- [Why would a commercial flight be landing with a tailwind?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/44776/why-would-a-commercial-flight-be-landing-with-a-tailwind/44779#44779)